# how do I keep the parent table available

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models: `User` and `Phone`

The `User` model has a field called `Phone_id` which is populated with the `Phone.id` field.

I am trying to loop through all phones and display the phone name and associated user extension number.

However, because of callbacks (I think) the phone object has gone when I get to the success method of the `getUser` method.

code is below :

```
var User = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/../models/User.js');
var Phone = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/../models/Phone.js');

Phone.hasOne(User,{ foreignKey: 'Phone_id'});

Phone.findAll().success(function(phones){
  for (var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
    phones[i].getUser().success(function(user){
      console.log(xxxx.Name, user.Extension);
    });
});
```

How can I display the phone name and user extension in the console.log statement iow, what do I need to put in place of xxxx ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested but something like

```
var User = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/../models/User.js');
var Phone = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/../models/Phone.js');

Phone.hasOne(User,{ foreignKey: 'Phone_id'});

Phone.findAll().success(function(phones){
  phones.forEach(function(phone) {
    phone.getUser().success(function(phone) {
      return function(user){
        console.log(phone.Name, user.Extension);
      }
    }(phone))
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is this:

```
var User = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/../models/User.js');
var Phone = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/../models/Phone.js');

Phone.hasOne(User,{ foreignKey: 'Phone_id'});

Phone.findAll().success(function(phones){
  phones.forEach(function(phone) {
    phone.getUser().success(function(user){
      console.log(phone.Name, user.Extension);
    });
  })
});
```